# Can you see added fields in discussion boards after connecting to Outlook?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, outlook, discussion-board

I have created a discussion board in my site and I have added extra fields of choice type and single line type in message content type so that i can add information to the fields in reply posts. When I connect my discussion board to Outlook, I see the new added fields are not displaying.

Is there anything need to change to help resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't believe you can show custom fields on the outlook view of the discussion board.  The outlook integration utilizes the existing posting functionality that has been in outlook for years.  I have been trying to customize the post form in outlook, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think it is possible to see fields you add to the Discusion Board in Outlook. One option is to let those who reply type out their choices.

If you'd like to do a survey and you don't want your users to go into the browser and you have the InfoPath client, you might try that instead.